# How to trigger Jenkins build on tag update

Tags: git, github, jenkins

In order to make it easy for developers to test a certain revision on the test environment, I'd like jenkins to build a specific tag, whenever it is (force) updated on Github. I know force updating tags is not recommended, but at least it's less messy than deleting and re-creating a branch.

I'm using a pipeline build, with [this](https://pastebin.com/xMM15Hb3) build configuration. The most important settings are:

- Repository - Advanced

  - Name: `origin`
  - Refspec: `+refs/tags/build/test`
- Branch specifier: `refs/tags/build/test`
- Additional Behaviours - Advanced clone behaviour:

  - Fetch tags: yes
  - Honor refspec on initial clone: yes
  - Shallow clone

It pulls [this](https://pastebin.com/BTW29Gtv) pipeline script. It has two stages, which are basically:

- Build: `mvn clean install`
- Deploy: `input message: 'Does the build work on the Testserver?', ok: 'Yes'`

The build works fine itself. The issue is with the Git polling / GitHub hook. The build is either not triggered, if I (force) update the tag and the tag points to a commit on a branch that is not master. Or it goes into an infinite build loop after manually triggering a build, if the master has a different revision than the tag.

Here's an example for a [Git Polling Log](https://pastebin.com/WK2WRk7V) that goes into an infinite loop after I triggered a build manually. This excerpt:

```
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 81db8cff7aee624510cfe6a5c806bdc8653d423c (refs/tags/build/test)
Ignoring refs/heads/with-gwt as it doesn't match any of the configured refspecs
Ignoring refs/heads/new_financial as it doesn't match any of the configured refspecs
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/master is: 5d5173ea8d8b2f0621e25de9dd3202c3c2a195c4
Done. Took 8.2 sec
Changes found
```

shows that the the last built revision is `81db8cf`. The `build/test` tag at this time also points to `81db8cf`, while master is at `5d5173e`.

Looking at this line from the [Git Polling Log](https://pastebin.com/WK2WRk7V):

```
> git ls-remote -h git@github.com:fhackenberger/infostars.git # timeout=10
Found 3 remote heads on git@github.com:fhackenberger/infostars.git
```

it becomes evident, that the Git Polling only looks at branches. What I would like it to do is something along this:

```
git ls-remote -t -h git@github.com:fhackenberger/infostars.git | grep 'refs/tags/build/test'
```

So the question is: *How can I tell Jenkins to poll **only my tag** when checking for new revisions to build?*

PS: If someone can give a better strategy for solving what I'd like to achieve, please feel free ;-)